# Making secondary Ip addres primary, without disrupting internet connectivity

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, netsh

I'm adding a secondary IP address with this command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address "Ethernet" NewIp 255.255.255.0
```

After that, I want to make this address primary (default), without disrupting internet connectivity.

Let's say I have the following Ip addresses:

- IP 1: 109.0.0.1
- IP 2: 109.0.0.2

I want to change the order , so that the applications I start after this use 109.0.0.2 by default instead of 109.0.0.1 :

- IP 1: 109.0.0.2
- IP 2: 109.0.0.1

How can I do this from cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to remove all the IP addresses and re-add them with the `skipassource` parameter:

```
netsh int ipv4 add address "Local Area Network 2" 109.0.0.1 255.255.255.240 skipassource=true
```

But this is *totally* going to disrupt your internet connectivity. There's nothing you can do about this.

Perhaps if you tell us your end goal, rather than this specific step, we can help you in general more (sounds like this might be a failover VIP scenario or something)

Comment: I want to change the external ip address ... the websites I connect to should see the second IP: 109.0.0.2 .  Can't this be done by adding a route?